# Convert GPS coordinates to EPSG:54004 on android

Tags: android, gps, gis, projection

I need to convert  GPS coordinates to  EPSG:54004 on android. Are there any libraries or formulas to accomplish the task?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this perhaps be something for you? http://johndeck.blogspot.se/2005/09/overlaying-mercator-projected-wms.html

Comment: I've ended with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Android, proj4j ("for java") is a good bet. A sample Android application showing Proj4J is here: https://github.com/devork/android-hello-proj4

There are some reported bugs when compiling proj4j on Android, so maybe this java projection library is worth trying: http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/